# What's the difference between delete[] and ::operator delete() in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, new-operator, delete-operator

I was watching a youtube series about data structures and how to made our-self data structure.
But then the Instructor replaced the `new[]` with `::operator new()` and `delete[]` with `::operator delete()`, is there any difference? cuz this is the first time for me to see the `::operator` thing in c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new-expressions `new T` and `new T[n]` create objects in memory that they acquire.
The delete-expressions `delete p` and `delete [] p` destroy objects and release the memory where they were stored.

`operator new`  is a memory allocation function, and `operator delete` is a memory deallocation function. They do not do anything more than manage memory, and correspond to C's `malloc` and `free`.
They have those names in order to avoid introducing more keywords to the language – "operator new" and "operator delete" are just funky ways of spelling "allocate" and "deallocate".

The `::` is the scope resolution operator and makes sure that these calls are specifically to the functions defined in the global scope.

The new-expressions and delete-expressions are not equivalent to these functions, but use them behind the scenes for memory management.

If you use `operator new` for allocating memory you must then also create an object in that memory, and if you release memory with `operator delete` you should first destroy the object that occupies the memory.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the `::` operator is called the scope-resolution operator. The usage in this case is so that the correct version of a function can be selected. If you overload `operator delete()`, or `operator new()` for some class, and inside the implementation, you try to call `delete` on a member, the name lookup will only find the overloaded version. Using `::operator delete()` resolves this by looking in the global namespace.

Here's an example from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete):

```
struct X {
    static void operator delete(void* ptr, std::size_t sz)
    {
        std::cout << "custom delete for size " << sz << '\n';
        ::operator delete(ptr);
    }
    static void operator delete[](void* ptr, std::size_t sz)
    {
        std::cout << "custom delete for size " << sz << '\n';
        ::operator delete(ptr);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`operator new` works by allocating memory dynamically for a single object, while `operator new[]` instead creates an `array` object.

Placing `::` before a command tells the compiler to employ the global namespace definition of that command, and not any possible overloaded version of it that might have been defined in your code.